gitlab archive is timing out
I am trying to migrate a project from one gitlab to other. I have created and configured runners on the new gitlab and it seems to create builds fine.
For one of the project in my previous gitlab yml file, I had a line where it gets a file from the gitlab directly like below..

build_package:
stage:
build
script:
- . <(git archive --remote git@old-gitlab.com:build-automation/build-scripts.git HEAD .pre-build.sh | tar -xO)

I tried to replicate the same here in new gitlab however it seems to timeout..

build_package:
stage:
build
script:
- . <(git archive --remote git@new-gitlab.com:build-automation/build-scripts.git HEAD .pre-build.sh | tar -xO)
ssh: connect to host new-gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out

Am I missing something obvious here?
I have tried updating the gitlab-runner, git versions and they are all of at the latest now.
Also on the old gitlab, i could see SSH and HTTP both where as on the new gitlab, i can only see http.
Also tried using the below instead but no luck.
curl -L https://new-gitlab.com/build-automation/build-scripts/-/archive/master/build-scripts-master.tar |tar -xO .pre-build.sh > .pre-build.sh

Since it gives a timeout error i would suspect either the new GitLab does not even listen on :22 or something on the networks blocks it (e.g. a firewall).
Can you test if the connection works manually using this tutorial? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#verify-that-you-can-connect

I just realised that in the old gitlab for this particular project, deploy keys were added. Could that be causing it? I have now added the public keys however doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.
Also in the new gitlab, I don't see the option of SSH but HTTP only for clone option. Does it mean ssh is not enabled or available?

Yes, it could be the case that SSH is disabled. It think this is done in gitlab.rb. Are you running GitLab in Docker or straight on a machine?

the new gitlab is hosted at the AWS and not managed by me.
I was trying it via curl by creating access token.
However it still seem to be redirecting to login page.
$ curl -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxx" -O https://new-gitlab.com/ci-build-automation/ci-build-scripts/raw/master/.ci-pre-build.sh
$ head .ci-pre-build.sh
You are being redirected.
I'd try to talk to the people managing the GitLab in AWS. If thats not possible, your best bet is probably to use HTTPs instead of SSH.
